# Python script to ssh to multiple switches send output of commands

Tags: python

Fairly new to python. I'm able to ssh to a switch and get the data needed using the below script but I need to pull this information from 100+ switches. What do I need to add to this script to achieve that? Thanks

```
from paramiko import client

class ssh:

    client = None

    def __init__(self, address, username, password):
        # Let the user know we're connecting to the server
        print("Connecting to switch.")
        # Create a new SSH client
        self.client = client.SSHClient()
        # The following line is required if you want the script to be able to access a server that's not yet in the known_hosts file
        self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(client.AutoAddPolicy())
        # Make the connection
        self.client.connect(address, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False)


    def sendCommand(self, command):
        if(self.client):
            stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command(command)
            while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
                # Print data when available
                if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
                    alldata = stdout.channel.recv(1024)
                    prevdata = b"1"
                    while prevdata:
                        prevdata = stdout.channel.recv(1024)
                        alldata += prevdata

                    print(str(alldata, "utf8"))
        else:
            print("Connection not opened.")

connection = ssh("x.x.x.x", "user", "pwd")
connection.sendCommand("show int status | e not")
```

Comment: How about writing a for loop and write the output of each instance to different txt files?

Answer (score 0):

swiches mean instance? so you want to run command on muti-machine? your can try fabric.

```
@roles("instance-group")
@task
def upload():
    """上传代码到测试服务器"""
    local("tar -zc -f /tmp/btbu-spider.tar.gz ../BTBU-Spider")
    put("/tmp/btbu-spider.tar.gz", "/tmp/")
    local('rm /tmp/btbu-spider.tar.gz')
    run("tar -zx -f /tmp/btbu-spider.tar.gz -C ~/test/")
```

then you can define "instance-group" ssh ip, you can call this function from local. but actually all this command are run at remote instance(not local function).

Answer (score 0):

Add the information about all the switches into a configuration file, for example like:

address1,username1,password1

address2,username2,password2

Each switch can be on a new line and arguments can be separated by just using a comma for ease of use. Then, open the file and  read lines one by one and parse them:

```
with open('switches.conf', 'r') as f:
    for line in f: # Read line by line
        params = line.split(',') # Split the three arguments by comma
        address = params[0]
        username = params[1]
        password = params[2]
        connection = ssh(address, username, password)
        connection.sendCommand("show int status | e not")
        with open(address, 'w+') as wf: # If you have to write any information about the switches, suggesting this method
            wf.write(..information to write..)
```

That must be done in the cycle. You can just call two functions in that cycle, the function that initializes the SSH connection and the function that gets the information, while this could be your main function. Of course the example for configuration is just a guideline, it has a lot of flaws, especially security ones, so you can make it however you want. Anyway, the idea is that you just need a cycle to do that and by having a configuration file to read from makes it a lot easier :) And you can save the information to different text files that are named by the addresses of the instances for example, as @Santosh Kumar suggested in the comments.
EDIT: Edited my answer and added an example for the connection and sending the command, as I hadn't noticed it was a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`parallel-ssh`](https://pypi.org/project/parallel-ssh) for running ssh cmds on multiple machines. Get it by running `pip install parallel-ssh

```
from pssh.clients import ParallelSSHClient

hosts = ['switch1', 'switch2']
client = ParallelSSHClient(hosts, user='my_user', password='my_pass')

output = client.run_command('show int status | e not')
for host, host_output in output.items():
    print host, "".join(host_output.stdout)
```

Comment: I get this error when trying to install parallel-ssh..      'ssh2/agent.c:569:10: fatal error: 'libssh2.h' file not found
    #include "libssh2.h"
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1'